# Creating common layout structures in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an application which can be installed on any android device. Where should I put the following code in manifest file?

```
<supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Also, I have created three folders layout-normal, layout-small and layout-large. Uniformly i maintain LinearLayout in all my layout and different resolution of images in drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, and drawable-ldpi.

The problem is layout is not suitable for some device, because it take different images based on density and i use mostly WRAP_CONTENT for most of component.

The alignment is not uniform in all device.

How can I maintain the Uniform alignment and common layout and images to support all android device Version?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly... you want to display the proper layouts based on screen densities. Is this correct?

If so then you will want to formally name your layout directories. From [Android: Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

> For example, the following is a list of resource directories in an
>   application that provides different layout designs for different
>   screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for medium, high, and
>   extra high density screens.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```