# Android common layout for all screen sizes

Tags: android

Could you tell me that how can I create a common single display interface for all devices?

**I tried** to use three linear layouts;

- First have a width and height = match+parent
- Second set width = match_parent and height = 70mm,
- Third layout set width = match_parent and height ## Heading ##= 8mm

But these occurs some problems; on small screen sized devices like galaxy y it goes high and about big screens like s3 it goes small in the half of screen. Please help me.

Comment: You MUST post your XML layout if you expect help from us... In general, you can design a liquid layout that expands to all devices making use of the weight property, or you can design several layouts, one per each size of screen (but this approach is more complicate to maintain, I usually take the first one).

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following links are help to you...

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

[Creating common layout structures in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748438/creating-common-layout-structures-in-android)